# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str - DB field is string, variable passed is number in string format

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a query which filters based on a string field, containing phone numbers with leading zero. My query uses `%s` as a placeholder with the variable passed to the query at execution time as so:

```
rows = (('01234567891',), ('01234567892',), ('01234567893',))

dbQuery2 = """
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(ch.start), '%d/%m/%Y') As CallDate,
             ch.did AS InboundNo,
             COUNT(*) AS DayTotal
      FROM call_history ch LEFT JOIN
           ast_queue_log aql
           ON aql.event = 'ENTERQUEUE' AND aql.callid = ch.callid
      WHERE ch.did = %s AND
            ch.start BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AND NOW()
      GROUP BY ch.did, DATE(ch.start)
      ORDER BY ch.did, DATE(ch.start)
     ;
"""

for row in rows:
    cur2.execute(dbQuery2, row)
    subrows = cur.fetchall()
```

The DB field that causes an issue is:

```
`did` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: and of you skip the tupples in rows and have only the numebrs?

Comment: basically your query works and the sqk is sound,  did you chekc the query in workbench, to test ot

Comment: Sample data might help

Comment: It definitely appears that the issue is that the query wants an integer rather than a string as the parameter - but the field is a string - what gives???

Answer (score 1):

The issue here are the `DATE_FORMAT` strings in the SQL query. The `%d`, `%m` and `%Y` are interpreted as variable placeholders and the MySQLdb engine tries to substitute the variable in there rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

Fixed by using the following format in the query:

```
dbQuery2 = """
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(ch.start), '%%d/%%m/%%Y') As CallDate,
         ch.did AS InboundNo,
         COUNT(*) AS DayTotal
  FROM call_history ch LEFT JOIN
       ast_queue_log aql
  ON aql.event = 'ENTERQUEUE' AND aql.callid = ch.callid
  WHERE ch.did = %s AND
            ch.start BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%%Y-%%m-01') AND NOW()
  GROUP BY ch.did, DATE(ch.start)
  ORDER BY ch.did, DATE(ch.start)
 ;
```

"""